# Problems building APK with OpenCV

Tags: android, flutter, dart, opencv, gradle

I recently incorporated OpenCV sdk for Android and have it running fine in debug and now I am trying to build an APK using flutter.

Whenever I use the command `flutter build apk --flavor prod` I get the error:

```
ERROR:C:\Users\Wesley\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\a70cc01f707cb65bbfec9756913c8264\transformed\jetified-opencv_android_module-3.1.0-fix3-runtime.jar: 
R8: Type org.opencv.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: 
C:\Users\Wesley\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\a70cc01f707cb65bbfec9756913c8264\transformed\jetified-opencv_android_module-3.1.0-fix3-runtime.jar:org/opencv/BuildConfig.class, 
C:\Mobile App\Mobile-App\mobile-app\build\sdk\intermediates\runtime_library_classes_jar\prodRelease\classes.jar:org/opencv/BuildConfig.class

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:minifyProdReleaseWithR8'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.R8Task$R8Runnable
   > Compilation failed to complete, origin: C:\Users\Wesley\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\a70cc01f707cb65bbfec9756913c8264\transformed\jetified-opencv_android_module-3.1.0-fix3-runtime.jar:org/opencv/BuildConfig.class

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 13s
Running Gradle task 'assembleProdRelease'...                       74.7s
Gradle task assembleProdRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Seeing as these files are both in a cache and the build folders, I first tried Invalidating Caches, next I tried deleting the .gradle folder, then I tried deleting the build folder, Then I tried every combination of these while resyncing gradle files, cleaning, and rebuilding.

I am implementing the OpenCV sdk in app/build.gradle like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.4')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ktx'
    implementation project(path: ':openCV:sdk')
}
```

I have no problem using OpenCV objects in my project and everything works while debugging. I've even tried copying my flavors to the OpenCV build.gradle but that doesn't do anything. Here's what my buildTypes and flavors look like:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            debuggable false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            shrinkResources false

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

flavorDimensions "appMode"
    productFlavors {
        qa {
            dimension "appMode"
            //applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "@string/app_name_qa"]
        }
        prod {
            dimension "appMode"
            manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "@string/app_name"]
        }
    }
```

I thought I knew what to do for an error like this but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging, I found that one of my packages was utilizing OpenCV and thus on build didn't know where to pull the reference from. I'm sure there is a way to exclude what is pulled from a package but I wasn't utilizing the package anyway so I just removed it.